# Execute a function after the source of Twitter bootstrap typeahead is loaded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm actually using the plugin Typeahead from Twitter bootstrap and I would like to add a new row after the data from my server are loaded.

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get('/typeahead.json', { q: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Once the data are loaded I would like to add a new row with the query at the end of the dropdown.

What is the trick to do that?

Answer (score 0):

U have to do some modifications to the following code -

```
// try using id instead of class  
//like id="#MyTypeahead"

var autocomplete = $('#MyTypeahead').typeahead();  
var srcArray = new Array();


// You should assign ur updated source here.  
srcArray = ["Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5"];  

srcArray.push("New line goes here");
autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = JSON.parse(srcArray);
```

And now your typeahead source look like this-
["Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","New line goes here"]